# Adding choice of notifications in chatrooms

Tags: feature-request, chat

I have recently noticed that notifications in chatrooms work in the same manner as in the comment section on the site. That is: you are only notified if your username is deliberately tagged (or if it's a comment on your question).

Would it be an idea to allow for notifications to all users that have participated in a specific chat when any new message is added?

This is what I would expect from being used to other chats, and I therefore forgot about a conversation completely while waiting for it to notify me because I am not aware that I must manually go there and look often. The chatrooms *are* different in use and purpose from comment sections, and you except to be a part of a conversation, not just to leave a comment - which thus needs a different reasoning for these notifications.

I can imagine an on/off button for the notifications, though, since some users might wish to exit the conversation for good at some point and let them avoid the nuisance of being notified.